# How I can use mysql in C++?

Tags: c++, mysql

I have searched a lot, all I found is a "mysql++" but I don't know how to install it.

I don't have knowledge about libraries in C++!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Searching google for "c++ mysql tutorial" brings back the following

[Developing Database Applications Using MySQL Connector/C++](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html)

and [A Tiny MySQL++ Tutorial; C++ and MySQL; MySQL++ Example](http://blog.code-head.com/a-tiny-mysql-tutorial-c-and-mysql-example)

Which in turn links to... [Installing MySQL++; How to install MySQL++ on Linux-CentOS](http://blog.code-head.com/installing-mysql-how-to-install-mysql-on-linux-centos)

And looking through the first article I found this [Installing MySQL Connector/C++ from Source](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/building-mysql-connector-cpp.html)

They all seem straight forward enough. Although installation processes vary slightly dependant on your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the library for your platform. Visual Studio can be used for Windows. The [official web page](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/) of mysql++ has a few FAQs.

Once you have the library compiled, you can go through the tutorials from [the manual](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/).

Comment: Sorry, I have never installed any library for C++, could you explain? I use Windows, I just need to compile it as "Visual Studio"? I am using "Dev C++".

Comment: It's probably not the root problem, but using Dev C++ is a pretty bad idea. It's really out of date and not entirely a great program. There are better free IDEs (Eclipse, Code::Blocks) out there.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have a running database to access?  If so, then mysql++ is straightforward.  There's nothing to install; just include the libraries and headers like any other code.  There is a simple example here:

http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/tutorial.html#simple

Comment: The problem is: I don't know how to install a library