# MySQL with C++ program

Tags: c++, mysql

I need to write a C++ Windows App to fetch data from a text file stored in a web site (http:.../my.txt) and contains data as follows :

```
m[mi++]="16.11.12 11:35:00|3366;3448;5352;431|3426;3508;5421;438|3396;3480;5364;443|3515;3598;5560;437|3622;3704;5741;472|3483;3561;5193;442|3454;3536;5464;440|3748;3835;5527;474|3385;3469;5367;436|3326;3413;4800;701;24|8092;8274;12800;688;30"

m[mi++]="19.12.12 11:35:00|3366;3448;5352;431|3426;3508;5421;438|3396;3480;5364;443|3515;3598;5560;437|3622;3704;5741;472|3483;3561;5193;442|3454;3536;5464;440|3748;3835;5527;474|3385;3469;5367;436|3326;3413;4800;701;24|8092;8274;12800;688;30"
```

I need to read the first 2 inputs of data (start with m[mi++]) each 2 minutes and take the first two parameters from each ones and store it in mySQL table as a script file as follows

```
Date                              Data

16.11.12 11:35:00             3366;3448;5352;431 
19.12.12 11:35:00             3366;3448;5352;431
```

Which C++ IDE (not MS visual studio) that is good to use with MySQL without any complication. I tried Netbeans and Eclipse but I've got errors with both MinG and Cygwin

Comment: Eng, it's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: He stated some stuffs unecessary but finally asked the real Question "Which C++ IDE (not MS visual studio) that is good to use with MySQL without any complication. I tried Netbeans and Eclipse but I've got errors with both MinG and Cygwin" though still not-seo-clear question

Comment: what it's still not obvious: sorry for that, the first part is the task that I want to do. I never used MySQL or build C++ Windows APP with Eclipse and other open source. I only used MSVisual studio C#

Comment: It sounds like your question boils down to "how do I use MySQL in C++?" to which I suggest looking at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792380/how-i-can-use-mysql-in-c

If ease of use is more important than the MySQL requirement, I suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576935/getting-started-with-sqlite-and-c

Comment: It's been a while. but thanks for the answer. I asked this question, because I want to do the task quickly and i already read articles about mySql, but still getting some error to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, its not about IDE. Everyting should work almost everywhere (if you have up to date compiller and set things up correctly). I personally use MSVS and [mysql++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/) library. Everything work just fine.

There is no such a thing as IDE for C++ and MySQL development. Just use IDE you want and add libraries correctly. You didnt wrote, what library are you using, so I cant help you more.

Comment: I appreciate your answers, I asked about the IDE so I can work with supported ones and because I don't want to work MVCS. Anyway, I am using Netbeans with mySQL connector C++. but I've got errors which I'll try to solve it. Thanks

Comment: I know that. But they asked me to do the task in different IDE than MVSC, so it works in other OS.

Comment: I write in MVSC and compile it under Linux or MacOS with no problem. If you use ANSI functions and no M$ stuff, then there is no problem

Answer (score 0):

I would say that CodeLite (codelite.org) or Code::Blocks (codeblocks.org are decent alternatives. You might need to Checkout wxDevCpp (DevCpp is dead), Anjuta, KDevelop, QT Creator and more.

I personally find MSVS a complicated IDE also I personally believe Eclipse and Netbeans should be used in Java (they Work with C++ both with right plugins)

My personal vote to CodeLite